# How to set default value in Guid column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has `1000s` of `Records`, I am adding a `new GUID()` column to this table with `Default GUID()` value.

**For ex. -** I want to set this particular `GUID()` **'3297F0F2-35D3-4231-919D-1CFCF4035975'** value to all existing records without using a Update query.

Comment: Create a new column and then run update command

Comment: Create a replica of your table and add the column GUID column as default and insert the records, After insert rename the new table with the actual table

Comment: You'd have to `DROP` the "old" table @RedDevil, and if there's any referential integrity that'll stop that.

Comment: When you add a new column to a table the values in the column will be NULL. You just need to add the new column and then update the current rows.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM tblaData

ALTER TABLE tblaData
ADD GUIDData VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3297F0F2-35D3-4231-919D-1CFCF4035975'


SELECT * FROM tblaData
```

Comment: Why varchar(50)? They are using a guid so uniqueidentifier is the correct datatype.